# Simple secure WCF config for single client, single server

Tags: wcf

I'm looking to configure wcf to transport data from one web server to another web server with exactly one service host and exactly one client.

Is there a simple security configuration available that does not require x509 certificates?

Additional info:
I may be looking for a simple configuration (message is okay) that could use a predetermined username / pw / enc, etc.  I'd also like to avoid sending a password in cleartext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "simple security configuration" you mean encrypting the transmissions between the end points, there's no simple, easy way without using x509 certificates, short of creating some kind of elaborate VPN connection point to point.

But using certificates with WCF doesn't have to be painful or expensive. Using message-level encryption (xml based) is easy enough to configure and get running, and since the communication is always between points "A" and "B", the obvious problems associate with using message encryption (distributing the certificates) isn't a problem at all.

The steps would be:
-Generate a self-signed x509 cert with public and private keys and copy to both servers

-Configure your clients and host to use message security

-install certs on both servers (plenty of documentation available, like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18601/An-easy-way-to-use-certificates-for-WCF-security))

-Configure your host and clients to find the certificates during startup

-run and test

After you've got everything running, you'd obviously replace your self-signed cert with a commercial version.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your platform. Are you on Windows? If so, you can use Windows credentials with message-level encryption and no need for certificates. [Here is a step by step guide on how to do it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734673(v=vs.110).aspx). Hope this helps!